# Trying to install Varnish on Ubuntu 14.04 server LTS

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, software-installation

I'm attempting to install Varnish cache on Ubuntu 14.04 and getting this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 varnish : Depends: libjemalloc1 (>=2.1.1) but it is not installable
           Depends: gcc but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is how I did it:

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https
apt-get install curl
curl https://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/GPG-key.txt | apt-key add -
echo "deb https://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/ trusty varnish-4.0" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnish-cache.list
apt-get update
apt-get install varnish
```

I just installed Trusty in a VMWare VM to do some testing with Nginx and Varnish. Any ideas on how to remedy?

Output from `apt-cache policy libjemalloc1`

```
libjemalloc1:
   Installed: (none)
   Candidate: (none)
   Version table:
```

Same output with

`apt-cache policy gcc`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libjemalloc1`

Comment: I have attempted to install 12.04.5 LTS as well with EXACTLY same results. WTH is going on here? I am following every freaking example on the internet but nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libjemalloc1` is in the universe repositories

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
```

`gcc` is in the main repositories

```
sudo apt-add-repository main
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install varnish
```

Comment: It's working. Great.